# Generate thumbnail from MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I'd like to generate a thumbnail UIImage from an MKMapView I create.

Unfortunately map tiles are not loaded until the MKMapView is actually in view on the screen. This means any delegate methods related to loading the map will not fire until the map was shown. Once the view which has the map on it is showing, the delegate methods fires just fine.

However, I'd like to generate a thumbnail instead of the map, so I can draw a more flat and efficient view later. The best example I have seen it Twitter for iPhone, but this almost looks like it's grabbed from online somehow, since it's using Google's own annotations.

Help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: have you found a way to do this with Apple Maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Google Maps with their Static Maps API.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

You can place pins on the map where you choose. You could also leave the map without annotations from Google and place icons over the image yourself since you would know the coordinates of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Since the iOS 7 days [MKMapSnapshotter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapsnapshotter) can be used to generate a [UIImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage) for a map region with various options. This will not include annotations and overlays but these can be drawn after-the-fact as a method is provided to translate coordinates into image points.

p.s., I know this is an old post but it comes up on Google searches and thought it would be nice to have something other than the Google maps reference above.